# Let $p$ be a prime of the form $3k+2$ that divides $a^2+ab+b^2$ for some integers $a,b$. Prove that $a,b$ are both divisible by $p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime of the form $3k+2$ that divides $a^2+ab+b^2$ for some integers $a,b$. Prove that $a,b$ are both divisible by $p$.

My attempt:

$p\mid a^2+ab+b^2 \implies p\mid (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)\implies p\mid a^3-b^3$
So, we have, $a^{3k}\equiv b^{3k}\mod p$ and by Fermat's Theorem we have, $a^{3k+1}\equiv b^{3k+1}\mod p$ as $p$ is of the form $p=3k+2$.

I do not know what to do next. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $p=3k+2$ is prime and 
$$
\left.p\ \middle|\ a^2+ab+b^2\right.\tag1
$$
then, because $a^3-b^2=(a-b)\left(a^2+ab+b^2\right)$, we have
$$
\left.p\ \middle|\ a^3-b^3\right.\tag2
$$
**Case $\boldsymbol{p\nmid a}$**

Suppose that $p\nmid a$, then $(2)$ says $p\nmid b$. Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
a^3&\equiv b^3&\pmod{p}\tag3\\
a^{3k}&\equiv b^{3k}&\pmod{p}\tag4\\
a^{p-2}&\equiv b^{p-2}&\pmod{p}\tag5\\
a^{-1}&\equiv b^{-1}&\pmod{p}\tag6\\
a&\equiv b&\pmod{p}\tag7\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation
$(3)$: $\left.p\ \middle|\ a^3-b^3\right.$
$(4)$: modular arithmetic
$(5)$: $3k=p-2$
$(6)$: if $p\nmid x$, then $x^{p-2}\equiv x^{-1}\pmod{p}$
$(7)$: modular arithmetic

Then, because of $(1)$ and $(7)$,
$$
\begin{align}
0
&\equiv a^2+ab+b^2&\pmod{p}\\
&\equiv 3a^2&\pmod{p}\tag8
\end{align}
$$
which, because $p\nmid 3$, implies that $p\mid a$, which contradicts $p\nmid a$ and leaves us with

**Case $\boldsymbol{p\mid a}$**

If $p\mid a$, then $(2)$ says $p\mid b$ and we get
$$
\left.p^2\ \middle|\ a^2+ab+b^2\right.\tag9
$$

Comment: Yes, this is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Use quadratic reciprocity.

$$4(a^2+ab+b^2)=(2a+b)^2+3b^2$$

so if 
$$a^2+ab+b^2\equiv 0 \pmod p$$ then 
$$(2a+b)^2\equiv -3b^2 \pmod p$$ and $-3$ is a quadratic residue so

$$\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=1.$$
However by reciprocity,

$$\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{-3}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=-1$$

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand from "and -3 is a quadratic residue..."

Comment: Do you mean the notation ?

Comment: No sir, the whole of it from that part.

Comment: Do you know the quadratic residue symbol $\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)$ ?

Comment: I think that I may not have seen it before.

Comment: The above symbol is $1$ if $q$ is a quadratic residue of $p$ and $-1$ othwise. Look up quadratic reciprocity, it will be explained there?

Comment: Ok, I did not know that before, yes, I will look it up on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You have shown that $a^3 \equiv b^3 \pmod p$. Remark that $(3, p-1)=1$ because $p=3k+2$. Thus we can write $3m + (p-1)n = 1$ for some integers $m, n$. Use this to show that $a\equiv b \pmod p$, so that $a^2+ab+b^2 \equiv 3a^2 \equiv 3b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$, and conclude from there.

(*P.S.* I have to commend you for posting your work!)

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot understand how to show that $a\equiv b\mod p$, sorry if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Dear @Swadhin, you are welcome. Use the identity $3m + (p-1)n = 1$ to rewrite the equation $a^{3m} \equiv b^{3m} \pmod p$... (You might want to assume at the beginning that $(a,p)=(b,p)=1$, so that raising to a negative exponent makes sense - then, at the end, conclude by contradiction.)

Comment: I am sorry sir, but I cannot seem to use the identity as you suggested. Will help me see that?

Answer (score 0):

By lil' Fermat, $a^{3k+1}\cong b^{3k+1}\bmod p\implies a\cdot
b^{3k}\cong b\cdot b^{3k}\bmod p$.  Thus $\begin{align} a\cong b\bmod p\implies a=b+pk \implies a^2+ab+b^2=(b+pk)^2+(b+pk)b+b^2=3b^2+3bpk+p^2k^2\end{align}$.  But this expression is divisible by $p$.  So $3b^2=-3bpk-p^2k^2+pl\implies p|3b^2\implies p|b\implies p|a$.